# Simplification of Momentums in FeynCalc

Tags: tensors, feyncalc

I have a little problem involving the following contraction in FeynCalc:

$$\frac{k^{\delta}k^{\sigma}}{k^2}$$

By hand one would lower $\sigma$ and contract with the other momentum to cancel $k^2$, obtaining:

$$\frac{k^{\delta}k^{\sigma}}{k^2}=\frac{k^{\delta}k_{\delta}}{k^2}g^{\delta\sigma}=g^{\delta\sigma}$$

The thing is that when doing it in FeynCalc I write

```
Contract[FV[k, \[Delta]] FV[k, \[Sigma]]/SP[k, k]]
```

but FeynCalc does not perform the contraction. If I specify how to do the contraction by lowering the $\sigma$ index

```
Contract[FV[k, \[Delta]] FV[k, \[Delta]] MT[\[Delta], \[Sigma]]/SP[k, k]]
```

then I obtain the metric tensor $g^{\delta\sigma}$, as it should be.

How can I perform this contraction in FeynCalc without lowering the index $\sigma$ explicitly? Something like the first option I put before.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but the question does not make any sense to me: when you lower $\sigma$, the dummy index you introduce cannot be named $\delta$ because it already exists in the expression as a free index. Unless I'm missing something here, you are explicitly violating Einstein's summation to obtain an incorrect result. If you give your dummy index a different name (say $\alpha$) you will see that the expression cannot be simplified any further.

Comment: Oh I see, you are completely right, then FeynCalc just did the right thing: doesn't simplify anything because this expression can't be simplified in the first place. Thank you!